# Why does the Schwinger limit fail to predict the electron radius?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, non-linear-systems

One might think that the minimum electron radius is given by the [Schwinger limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit), since, were it smaller, spontaneous radiative effects might begin to occur. This value is 3.3*10^-14 m, but we know that rMax is about 10^-22 m. So what do we suppose goes on over those (at least) 6 orders of magnitude where the electric field exceeds the Schwinger limit and yet we see nothing untoward?

Comment: Why would spontaneous "radiation effects" occur? Where would the energy for these effects come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why does the Schwinger limit fail to predict the electron radius?**

Because the electron radius isn't <10ˉ²² m. That's a wrong inference. It's quantum *field* theory, not quantum point-particle theory. The electron's field *is what it is*. In QFT it's an excitation of the electron field, not some point-particle speck with a field around it.

That's the short answer. To justify it I need to take a detour into fundamental physics. See where the Wikipedia [Schwinger limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwinger_limit) article says *the limit is typically reported as a maximum electric field before nonlinearity for the vacuum of*

$E_S = \frac{m_e^2 c^3}{q_e \hbar} \simeq 1.3 \times 10^{18} \, \mathrm{V} / \mathrm{m}$

Well, in classical electrodynamics the electron doesn't actually have an electric field, it has an *electromagnetic* field, or is such a field. We make it out of electromagnetic waves in [pair production](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pair_production), it has a wave nature, we can [diffract](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_diffraction) it, it has a [magnetic moment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_magnetic_moment#Magnetic_moment_of_an_electron), the [Einstein-de Haas effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein%E2%80%93de_Haas_effect#Description) demonstrates *"that spin angular momentum is indeed of the same nature as the angular momentum of rotating bodies as conceived in classical mechanics"*, the [Schrödinger equation is a wave equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation#The_wave_equation_for_particles), in [atomic orbitals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomic_orbital#Electron_properties) electrons *"exist as standing waves"*, and we don't talk of [spinors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinor) for nothing. IMHO there's good scientific evidence that electron is a field-variation, a wave, in a closed spin ½ path, such that what was a field variation now looks like a standing field. IMHO to visualize that field, you note section 11.10 of Jackson's [Classical Electrodynamics](https://archive.org/stream/ClassicalElectrodynamics/Jackson-ClassicalElectrodynamics#page/n397/mode/2up) where he says *"one should properly speak of the electromagnetic field Fμν rather than E or B separately".* Then you take a tip from [Maxwell](http://www.clerkmaxwellfoundation.org/MathematicalClassificationofPhysicalQuantities_Maxwell.pdf) who combined curl and convergence like this:

[image]

...to combine radial electric field lines with concentric magnetic field lines like so:

[image]

Note how the electromagnetic field (on the right) is looking something like depictions of the [gravito-magnetic field](http://science.nasa.gov/science-news/science-at-nasa/2011/04may_epic/) and [vector fields](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lhk8y1LkSq1qbdydv.png). Note too that the electron's Compton wavelength of 2.426 x 10ˉ¹² m is twice the circumference of the inner circle because it's a spin ½ particle with a 720° rotation. But also note that the radius of that circle isn't the radius of the electron, any more than the radius of the eye of the storm is the radius of a [cyclone](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tropical_cyclone). Talking of which, you can hopefully envisage that electrons and positrons move towards one another and around one another like cyclones and anticyclones: *co-rotating vortices repel, counter-rotating vortices attract*. When we only see the linear force we talk of an electric field, but there isn't really any such field. The linear and/or rotational motion is the result of *two* electromagnetic fields interacting, it takes two to tango:

[image]

And whilst it exists, positronium doesn't have much of an electromagnetic field because the electron and positron have "exchanged field". This is described as a virtual photon exchange, wherein virtual photons are field quanta, but they aren't actually throwing photons at one another. Ditto for electrons and protons. Hydrogen atoms don't twinkle.

Anyway, I didn't mean to write so much, but I hope it's enough to justify what I was saying. I hope you can now appreciate that saying the electron has a maximum radius of 10ˉ²² m is like hanging out of helicopter probing a whirlpool with a bargepole. Then when you can't feel the billiard ball, you say the billiard ball must be really small. But there *is* no billiard ball. Because it's quantum *field* theory. *Everything is field and waves*.

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is anything "untoward" is taken into account using renormalization - virtual electron-positron pairs screen the bare charge.